# Dot product/Scalar product with lengths

Tags: vectors

I have a question about finding the dot product when I am given only $\left|a\right|=5$, $\left|b\right|=3$ and $\left|a-b\right|=6$. Have no given angle between vectors so how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Hint: $\left|a-b\right|^{2}=\left<a-b,a-b\right>$, now expand the expression.

Comment: @eranreches still doesn't help me :(

Comment: @eranreches (Not OP) I'm not sure I understand the hint, could you elaborate a bit more slightly? How does a scalar, $|a-b|^2$, equal a vector?

Comment: @yolobird What do you know about dot product? I'll just note that $\left<a,b\right>=a\cdot b$ in case you are not familiar with this notation.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek $\left<a-b,a-b\right>$ is the dot product of the vector $a-b$ with itself, hence a scalar.

Comment: @eranreches I do know that **⟨a,b⟩=a⋅b**, but I still don't know how that hint would help me.

Comment: @eranreches Ahhhh, it was the notation that threw me off! I usually see $a \cdot b$ as you realized. I recall sitting in on a Lie Algebra class while visiting somewhere and seeing the $\left< a,b\right>$ notation used for inner products, so I apologize for not realizing that immediately :)

Comment: @yolobird So use the fact that $\left<a,b+c\right>=\left<a,b\right>+\left<a,c\right>$ and $\left<b+c,a\right>=\left<b,a\right>+\left<c,a\right>$ to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You have 
$$\left<a-b,a-b\right>=|a-b|^2$$
and simplifying:
$$\left<a,a-b\right>-\left<b,a-b\right>=\left<a,a\right>-\left<a,b\right>-\left<b,a\right>+\left<b,b\right>=36$$
and because 
$$\left<b,b\right>=b\cdot b=|b|^2=9$$
and 
$$\left<a,a\right>=a\cdot a=|a|^2=25$$
and because of commutativity
$$\left<a,b\right>=\left<b,a\right>=a\cdot b$$
we get
$$25-2a\cdot b+9=36$$
$$-2a\cdot b=2$$
$$a\cdot b = -1$$